# How to get value of json data using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json, vk-sdk

This is JSON data

```
{"response":[{"uid":1,"first_name":"Павел","last_name":"Дуров","hidden":1}]}
```

How to get  "first_name" value using SwiftyJSON

i tried so

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?", parameters: ["user_id": ID])
            .responseJSON { response in


                if let jsonData = response.result.value {
                    let first_name = JSON(jsonData)["first_name"].string
                    print("First name = \(first_name)")

                }
        }
```

but in output i have this: First name = nil

please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for your "response" key is an array.

```
let result = JSON(jsonData)["response"].arrayValue
let first_name = result[0]["first_name"].string
```

*Remember, JSON arrays begin with `[` and JSON dictionaries begin with `{`.*